# How to write SQL join in HQL in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

would you guys please help me with converting this SQL query into HQL query?

```
SELECT * FROM Client 
JOIN Member on Client.workspace_id = Member.myworkspaceid 
WHERE Member.id = {param}
```

I am trying different combinations of this :

```
"select p from Client as p 
 join Member m on p.workSpace_Id = m.myWorkSpaceId
 where m.id = :id"
```

But no matter how hard I try. I still missing something.

Member doesn't have any relations with Client

Comment: is Member have any relationship with Client ?

Comment: this will help: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-query-language-hql-example

Comment: @TipuSultan No it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hql you can specify the join (Hibernate doc : [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins))

You can join only if the relation is mapped in your entity class.

Based on your code (assuming that Member is mapped on attribute "member" the hql should look like:

```
select p from Client as p where p.member.id = :id
```

To understand relationship mapping take a look a this doc [JPA Relationship](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships)

Comment: So there might be problem, I don't have it mapped properly.

Do I need some special annotation for mapping the member in Client entity class?

Comment: It depends on the relation take a look at this link https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships